# Telegram bot. How do I send messages back?

Tags: python, telegram

I am creating a telegram chat bot, and I want to make sure that the messages of users that they write inside the bot are sent to me in private messages by the bot. I could reply to this message and my reply would be forwarded back to the user.

I've reread a lot of guides on telebot, and I haven't found anything like this. How could I implement such a feature?